# Cannot get grid to render using the SlickGrid examples

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, slickgrid

We are trying to stand up datagrid using SlickGrid as part of a project.

We are traditionally desktop developers, but implemented an MVC solution with SQL back-end to address a set of specific needs within our office (so, intranet only).

SlickGrid was appealing for a number of reason. We downloaded the NuGet package and attempted to stand up one of the examples (Example 3). We removed all boiler-plate MVC code from the *.cshtml page to minimize any additional variables.

When the page loads, most of the HTML renders, with the exception of the datagrid itself - just a big, blank area where the datagrid would be.

We're sure we missed something - a reference in the _Layout.cshtml? ...maybe a prerequisite?

We're using Visual Studio 2015 Pro, update 3.
.NET v4.5.1.

SlickGrid v2.2.20140120.
jQuery v3.5.1.
jQuery.event.drag v2.2.0.

Entity Famework v6.4.4.

Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization v1.1.3
Microsoft.Web.Infrastruction v1.0.0.

Comment: It would help if you showed us the code you have. And post any exceptions from .Net or at client side dev tools.

Comment: We are using the example, unaltered, provided by SlickGrid (eample3) in the *.cshrml (view) page...nothing more.  The following URL will show you exactly what we are trying to render:

https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example3-editing.html

Thank you.

Comment: I see part of the problem - the script tags in the sample file reference different paths and *.js versions/files than we have installed.  Tried updating the various NuGet packages, primarily the jQuery packages, and ended creating more confusion.  

I'm going to reset and take a harder look at what is needed, what we have, and what packages and versions we might want to download.

Comment: SlickGrid has been set up as a nuget download by a contributor, but essentially Slickgrid is a toolkit, and we don't really offer it as a drop-in component - this is deliberate as there are a huge range of use cases and it generally needs to be integrated with existing infrastructure. So it won't be hard to set up, but you will need to do a bit of tinkering to make sure all the script references are correct. On the plus side, Slickgrid is 100% client side, so once all the js and css packages are in place, it will just work. I'm making this point because it is not like other NuGet packages